# SQL Condensing multiple rows into one

Tags: sql, sql-server

I got the following SQL statement which results in the first table below.
My goal is to have an output like seen in the bottom table.
How do I achieve that?

```
SELECT tabDynValues.Dynamic_Field_ID,
       tabDynValues.Record_ID,
       CASE Dynamic_Field_ID
        WHEN 755 THEN tabDynValues.Value_Char
       END Filiale,
       CASE Dynamic_Field_ID
        WHEN 756 THEN tabDynValues.Value_Double
       END AD,
       CASE Dynamic_Field_ID
        WHEN 757 THEN tabDynValues.Value_Double
       END Vertrieb,
       CASE Dynamic_Field_ID
        WHEN 758 THEN tabDynValues.Value_Double
       END Expansion
  FROM CI_AM_Dynamic_Field_Value tabDynValues
 WHERE tabDynValues.Activity_ID = 100612
   AND tabDynValues.Dynamic_Field_ID IN (SELECT Dynamic_Field_ID
                                           FROM CI_AM_Dynamic_Field
                                          WHERE Dynamic_Field_Group_ID = 238)
ORDER BY tabDynValues.Record_ID, tabDynValues.Dynamic_Field_ID
```

| Dynamic_Field_ID | Record_ID | Filiale | AD | Vertrieb | Expansion |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 755 | 1 | 1111 Mitte | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 756 | 1 | NULL | 123 | NULL | NULL |
| 757 | 1 | NULL | NULL | 56 | NULL |
| 758 | 1 | NULL | NULL | NULL | 45 |
| 755 | 2 | 2222 Ost | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 756 | 2 | NULL | NULL | 120 | NULL |
| 755 | 3 | 3333 West | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 756 | 3 | NULL | 123 | NULL | NULL |
| 757 | 3 | NULL | NULL | 456 | NULL |
| 758 | 3 | NULL | NULL | NULL | 789 |

| Dynamic_Field_ID | Record_ID | Filiale | AD | Vertrieb | Expansion |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | 1 | 1111 Mitte | 123 | 56 | 45 |
|  | 2 | 2222 Ost | 120 | NULL | NULL |
|  | 3 | 3333 West | 123 | 456 | 789 |

Comment: Do a GROUP BY! !

Comment: @jarlh a GROUP BY does not work here.

Comment: @Raphnika,  definitely GROUP BY works here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a `GROUP BY` and wrap your case expressions inside `MAX` function:

```sql
SELECT
    tabDynValues.Record_ID,
    MAX(CASE Dynamic_Field_ID WHEN 755 THEN tabDynValues.Value_Char END) Filiale,
    MAX(CASE Dynamic_Field_ID WHEN 756 THEN tabDynValues.Value_Double END) AD,
    MAX(CASE Dynamic_Field_ID WHEN 757 THEN tabDynValues.Value_Double END) Vertrieb,
    MAX(CASE Dynamic_Field_ID WHEN 758 THEN tabDynValues.Value_Double END) Expansion
FROM CI_AM_Dynamic_Field_Value tabDynValues
WHERE tabDynValues.Activity_ID = 100612 AND tabDynValues.Dynamic_Field_ID IN (
    SELECT Dynamic_Field_ID
    FROM CI_AM_Dynamic_Field
    WHERE Dynamic_Field_Group_ID = 238
)
GROUP BY tabDynValues.Record_ID
ORDER BY tabDynValues.Record_ID
```